# Trying to render a link within a string, within JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html-email

I'm trying to render a link, which is found in an array of objects with properties and values.

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "This is a title",
    body: [
      "This is some stuff. Lorem ipsum, lorizzle for shizzle.",
      "Click here to send an <Link to="mailto:yo@mail.com">email</Link>"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "This is another title",
    body: [
      "Moar stuff.",
      "Here is ma' <Link to="mailto:hello@mail.com">email</Link>"
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm using this logic to map through the array's objects and store them inside an array of components. This works as intended, if all I'm intending to do is just render some text in a paragraph. When it comes to links, simply this won't work. My guess is that React takes the string for text, and renders the entire thing as text. It doesn't care of the contents.

```
            <section key={item.key} className="">
                <h2 className="text-base">{item.title}</h2>
                {
                    item.body.map(function(paragraph) {
                        return(
                            <p className="text-sm">{paragraph}</p>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </section>
```

I've tried enclosing the Link tags within curly braces, to concatenate the string and email (as it would appear in the HTML), string template literals. Nothing worked.

I'm not sure there is a dependency I'm missing or a step. Perhaps the approach I'm taking is wrong? Maybe what I'm trying to do is impossible in React?

Would appreciate some light shed on this matter.

Comment: Where this array of items come from ? External API ? Or you hard-coded it somewhere in your project ?

Comment: @ sara, have updated with the info, kindly check and let me know if it helped you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a very naive approach to transfering jsx within array.

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "This is a title",
    body: [
      ["This is some stuff. Lorem ipsum, lorizzle for shizzle."],
      ["Click here to send an ", <Link to="mailto:yo@mail.com">email</Link>"]
    ]
  },
```

```
item.body.map(function(paragraph) {
    const content = paragraph.reduce((combined, elem) => {
        return content + elem;
    });

    return(
        <p className="text-sm">{paragraph}</p>
    )
});
```

Comment: I wanted to try this solution first, because it seemed the simplest.

I first converted the strings with emails into arrays (as you've mentioned in the first part of your solution) and it worked right away.

Now I'm wondering why it worked, without the need to reduce the array.

Thank you for the simple solution! It worked perfectly :D

Comment: Well, as it appears, an array passed directly to JSX is rendered explicitly... If it's a correct answer, please mark it as correct and give a +1, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections in your question what i found

Assuming you wanted to have a anchor tag

so tweaking your array , Changes

1. `<a href='mailto:yo@mail.com'>email</a>` instead of  `<Link to="mailto:yo@mail.com">email</Link>`
2. `"Click here to send an <Link to="mailto:yo@mail.com">email</Link>"` instead `"Click here to send an <a href='mailto:yo@mail.com'>email</a>"`, quotes should be used properly inside double quotes you need to have single quotes or vice versa

Doing the above changes adding the solution

Here you can have multiple approaches

1. Using a library

Example
[html-react-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-react-parser)

Code Snippet

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import Parser from "html-react-parser";

const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "This is a title",
    body: [
      "This is some stuff. Lorem ipsum, lorizzle for shizzle.",
      "Click here to send an <a href='mailto:yo@mail.com'>email</a>"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "This is another title",
    body: [
      "Moar stuff.",
      "Here is ma' <a href='mailto:hello@mail.com'>email</a>"
    ]
  }
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {arr.map(item => (
        <section key={item.key} className="">
          <h2 className="text-base">{item.title}</h2>
          {item.body.map(function(paragraph) {
            return <p className="text-sm">{Parser(paragraph)}</p>;
          })}
        </section>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

2. Use the [dangerouslySetInnerHtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml), but this method has some flaws as mentioned in the docs

> dangerouslySetInnerHTML is React’s replacement for using innerHTML in
> the browser DOM. In general, setting HTML from code is risky because
> it’s easy to inadvertently expose your users to a cross-site scripting
> (XSS) attack.

Code snippet

**App.js**

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";

const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "This is a title",
    body: [
      "This is some stuff. Lorem ipsum, lorizzle for shizzle.",
      "Click here to send an <a href='mailto:yo@mail.com'>email</a>"
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "This is another title",
    body: [
      "Moar stuff.",
      "Here is ma' <a href='mailto:hello@mail.com'>email</a>"
    ]
  }
];
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {arr.map(item => (
        <section key={item.key} className="">
          <h2 className="text-base">{item.title}</h2>
          {item.body.map(function(paragraph) {
            return (
              <p
                className="text-sm"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: paragraph }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </section>
      ))}
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

In the above approach, you can do a [dompurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify) and set with dangerouslysetinnerhtml to avoid the XSS attacks

```
import DOMPurify from "dompurify";

<p
  className="text-sm"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: DOMPurify.sanitize(paragraph) }}
/>;
```

I hope this will give a better understanding

Answer (score 0):

you might try using `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`.

Something like this: `<div dangerouslySetInnerHtml={paragraph} />`

This attribute is named like that with a reason, so be careful about what you send in there, as it might lead to XSS injections.

Learn more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml